# What job opportunities are there for low time pilots in Malaysia?

Tags: flight-training, career, airline-pilot, malaysia

Does a new pilot who has just obtained ATPL license has job opportunities?

When I search at pilot job offered on Internet, they mostly required more than 3,500+ flying hours. What I knew about those who obtained ATPL license have flying hours aroun 1500 hours. It mostly includes aviation academy training used turboprop engine plane and they are very light weight. The jobs ads require those pilot who have flown aircraft more than 40,000 lbs.

Will a new pilot get an opportunity to get such a job? How does new pilot get their job under these kind of conditions?

Comment: Related: [What can a new commercial pilot do to build flight time?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/371)

Answer (score -1):

Malaysia I suspect would be very similar to where i started working a few years back in Africa. In countries (continent) like that you really need to be there if you are a low timer. Hanging around the airports and meet people who could help you with finding your first opportunity forget about sending CV's from miles away hoping for an opportunity, key here is to be pro active and make yourself known locally....